# Add to PATH variable with Openshift Jekyll Cartridge

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, openshift, jekyll

I want to use the pandoc markdown plugin for jekyll on Openshift. This requires changing the PATH variable, such that the pandoc executable can be placed in the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. I've forked the [jekyll cartridge](https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-jekyll-cartridge) and attempted to mimic the way env is setup in bin/setup there.

The ruby path element was setup like this:

```
dirname $(scl enable ruby193 "which ruby") > $env_dir/OPENSHIFT_RUBY_PATH_ELEMENT
```

So, I tried this:

```
dirname $(scl enable ruby193 "printenv OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") > $env_dir/OPENSHIFT_JEKYLL_PATH_ELEMENT
```

Thinking that perhaps this counted as a ruby cartridge, even though the short name is "jekyll," I also tried:

```
dirname $(scl enable ruby193 "printenv OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") > $env_dir/OPENSHIFT_RUBY_PATH_ELEMENT
```

I also tried:

```
dirname echo $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR > $env_dir/OPENSHIFT_JEKYLL_PATH_ELEMENT
dirname echo $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR > $env_dir/OPENSHIFT_RUBY_PATH_ELEMENT
```

Finally, in `env/` I placed a file `OPENSHIFT_JEKYLL_PATH_ELEMENT.erb` with the following line:

```
<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'] %>
```

My reason for attempting this last was due to the [cartridge developer's guide](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html):

> The PATH variable is set by OpenShift with the base being /etc/openshift/env/PATH. If you provide an OPENSHIFT_{Cartridge-Short-Name}_PATH_ELEMENT, OpenShift will include the value when building the PATH when your scripts are run or an application developer does an interactive log on.

SSHing to the server and checking `echo $PATH` revealed no change to the environment variable. I've read the [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720952/set-env-path-in-openshift) regarding openshift and setting the path and I either try those solutions above or they find some way to avoid setting the path.

I'm lost…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would probably need to be done in an [Action Hook](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-modifying-applications.html#customizing-openshift-build-process) on your application. Basically you'll append your steps above to the deploy script to see if you can change that `$PATH` value.